# How to connect the MSSQL server with Hapi framework?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, hapi

I am new in node and like to learn about creating an API using node. Meanwhile, I search for a good framework for that and I start with the #hapi Framework. I like to know the way to connect #hapi with the MSSQL server.

Comment: Hi there. What have you tried, and what have you googled for the answer. This is anyway a possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680822/i-am-trying-to-connect-to-connect-to-my-sql-server-database-with-node-and-hapi-j

Comment: Ok, let me check that.